# R Given a list of same dimension data tables, produce a summary of the means of each cell

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

I'm finding it hard to put what I want into words so I will try to run through an example to explain it. Let's say I've repeated an experiment twice and have two tables:

```
[df1]   [df2]
 X Y     X Y
 2 3     4 1
 5 2     2 4
```

These tables are stored in a list (where the list can contain more than two elements if necessary), and what I want to do is create an average of each cell in the tables across the list (or for a generalised version, apply any function I choose to the cells i.e. mad, sd, etc)

```
[df1]   [df2]         [dfMeans]
 X Y     X Y        X          Y
 2 3     4 1     mean(2,4) mean(3,1)
 5 2     2 4     mean(5,2) mean(2,4)
```

I have a code solution to my problem, but since this is in R there is most likely a cleaner way to do things:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X=c(2,3,4),Y=c(3,2,1))
df2 <- data.frame(X=c(5,1,3),Y=c(4,1,4))
df3 <- data.frame(X=c(2,7,4),Y=c(1,7,6))
dfList <- list(df1,df2,df3)

dfMeans <- data.frame(MeanX=c(NA,NA,NA),MeanY=c(NA,NA,NA))

for (rowIndex in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (colIndex in 1:ncol(df1)) {
    valuesAtCell <- c()
    for (tableIndex in 1:length(dfList)) {
      valuesAtCell <- c(valuesAtCell, dfList[[tableIndex]][rowIndex,colIndex])
    }
    dfMeans[rowIndex, colIndex] <- mean(valuesAtCell)
  }
}

print(dfMeans)
```

Comment: Is the order of rows important across the data frames?

Comment: I can always resort them later so it's not necessary

Comment: I meant: Is the mean to be applied row-wise across the data frames?

Comment: Cell-wise, each of the data frames in the list is a repeat of an experiment thus:

`mean(c(dfList[[1]][1,1], dfList[[2]][1,1])`
`mean(c(dfList[[1]][i,j], dfList[[2]][i,j])`

is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution where the mean is applied row-wise across the data frames:

```
library(data.table)

dtList <- rbindlist(dfList, use.names = TRUE, idcol = TRUE)
dtList
   .id X Y
1:   1 2 3
2:   1 3 2
3:   1 4 1
4:   2 5 4
5:   2 1 1
6:   2 3 4
7:   3 2 1
8:   3 7 7
9:   3 4 6

dtList[, rn := 1:.N, by = .id][][, .(X = mean(X), Y = mean(Y)), by = rn]
   rn        X        Y
1:  1 3.000000 2.666667
2:  2 3.666667 3.333333
3:  3 3.666667 3.666667
```

You can replace the `mean` by another aggregation function, eg, `median`. The `.id` column numbers the original data frames each row was sourced from.

**Edit**

The solution can be extended to an *arbitrary* number of columns (provided column names and column order are identical in all data frames):

```
cn <- colnames(df1)
cn
[1] "X" "Y"

dtList[, rn := 1:.N, by = .id][, lapply(.SD, mean), by = rn, .SDcols = cn][, rn := NULL][]
          X        Y
1: 3.000000 2.666667
2: 3.666667 3.333333
3: 3.666667 3.666667
```

The column names are taken from one of the original data frames which adds to the flexibility of the solution. `[, rn := NULL]` removes the row numbers from the result, `[]` ensures the result ist printed.

Comment: For the last line, why can't you just `dtList[, .(X = mean(X), Y = mean(Y)), by = .id]`?

Comment: @RichieCotton The OP wants to compute the mean cell-wise across the data frames. So, the mean is computed row-wise for each column separately.

Comment: Perhaps, another approach could be to reshape the combined data frames.

Comment: Just found another issue, is there any way to handle any number of columns rather than just `X` and `Y`? i.e. When you don't know the number of columns or their names until the code runs

Comment: @AlexSpedding The extended solution in my answer addresses the case of an arbitrary number of columns where the column names are only defined in the original data frames.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply sum all `data.frame`'s in your `list` using `Reduce()`, and divide by the length of `dfList`, which is equal to the number of `df`'s it contains.

```
Reduce(`+`, dfList) / length(dfList)
#         X        Y
#1 3.000000 2.666667
#2 3.666667 3.333333
#3 3.666667 3.666667
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for means, but is there a way to substitute the + for a function name such as if I want to apply more complex functions to the data... Something like:

`Reduce(FUNCTION_NAME, dfList)`

Comment: The first argument of `Reduce()` is always a function, which in our case happens to be `+`. See `?Reduce`.

Comment: @mtoto. This does _not_ work for *any* function. Simply substituting `+` by `mean` in `Reduce` will result in an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what the criteria for functions used in `Reduce` are but `intersect` works, but functions such as `mean` `sd` and `mad` don't

Comment: According to `?Reduce` _a function of the appropriate arity (binary for Reduce,..._ is required.

Comment: @UweBlock I never said you could replace `+` by `mean` in this example.