# Calculating standard deviation of variables in a large list in R

Tags: r

I have a large list that contains 1000 lists of the same variables and same length.

My goal is to calculate mean, standard deviation, and standard error of all lists within the large list.

I have calculated mean of the variables using `Reduce()`, but I couldn't figure out how to do the same for standard deviation.

My list looks something like this:

```
large.list <- vector('list', 1000)

for (i in 1:1000) {
    large.list[[i]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:4), ncol=2))
}

large.list

[[1]]
   V1  V2
1   1   3
2   2   4

[[2]]
   V1  V2
1   1   3
2   2   4

[[3]]
   V1  V2
1   1   3
2   2   4

......

[[1000]]
   V1  V2
1   1   3
2   2   4
```

To calculate mean, I do:

```
list.mean <- Reduce("+", large.list) / length(large.list)

list.mean

   V1   V2
1   1    3
2   2    4
```

This is overly simplified version of a large list, but how can I calculate list-wide standard deviation and standard error like I did for mean?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of question [R Given a list of same dimension data tables, produce a summary of the means of each cell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38475103/3817004).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I already had a solution to calculate list-wide mean, which is identical to mtoto's answer in your suggested post. My main problem was to calculate list-wide SD, which posts below resolved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you stay with `Reduce()`, you have to do a little bit statistics:**

```
var(x) = E(x^2) - (E(x))^2
```

Note that you already got `E(x)` as `list.mean`. To get `E(x^2)`, it is also straightforward:

```
list.squared.mean <- Reduce("+", lapply(large.list, "^", 2)) / length(large.list)
```

Then variance is:

```
list.variance <- list.squared.mean - list.mean^2
```

Standard deviation is just

```
list.sd <- sqrt(list.variance)
```

**However, a much more efficient solution is to use `tapply()`**

```
vec <- unlist(large.list, use.names = FALSE)
DIM <- dim(large.list[[1]])
n <- length(large.list)

list.mean <- tapply(vec, rep(1:prod(DIM),times = n), mean)
attr(list.mean, "dim") <- DIM
list.mean <- as.data.frame(list.mean)

list.sd <- tapply(vec, rep(1:prod(DIM),times = n), sd)
attr(list.sd, "dim") <- DIM
list.sd <- as.data.frame(list.sd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second solution was indeed a lot more efficient. One downside was that the row names and column names were removed. I added rownames and colnames functions to resolve the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an alternative, you could transform the list into a 3-dimensional matrix, and then use `apply()` to produce the output.

Here's how to transform the list (assuming dimensional regularity):

```
m <- do.call(cbind,lapply(large.list,as.matrix));
m <- array(m,c(nrow(m),ncol(m)/length(large.list),length(large.list)));
```

And here's how to use `apply()` on the matrix:

```
apply(m,1:2,mean);
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    3
## [2,]    2    4
apply(m,1:2,sd);
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    0    0
## [2,]    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

here a solution based on reshaping the list into data.table. we are basically extracting the value of index i from each sub-list to create a single vector.

```
ll <- unlist(large.list)
DX <- data.table(V1= ll[c(T,F,F,F)],
                 V2= ll[c(F,T,F,F)],
                 V3= ll[c(F,F,T,F)],
                 V4= ll[c(F,F,F,T)])
```

then all calculation are straight forward:

```
mm <- DX[,lapply(.SD,mean)]
sdd <- DX[,lapply(.SD,sd)]
```